# How to make the images same fit or same size?

Tags: javascript, css, django, e-commerce

I'm developing an e-commerce project in django, I have created a model for images and tried to resize or thumbnail the images but it seems this is not working for my case or maybe this is Front-end issue. When the vendor uploads the image products, I want the image products to fit and look in the same line regardless of the image original size. I don't want them to show like in this picture
[image]

so I want the price and button to be in the same line. I tried to resize the images but won't work

Comment: It's answered on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379727/make-images-the-same-size-in-bootstrap-grid

Comment: @psychodeveloper I tried that solution, but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a front end man but i think this should help ... thats about how to get size for the image you get from ImageField

```
<img src="{{ image.url }}" width="{{ image.width }}" height="{{ image.height }}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `object-fit` in CSS

```css
img{
  width:350px;
  height:200px;
  border:1pt solid #f00;
}
.cover{
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
.contain{
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508921912186-1d1a45ebb3c1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80"><br/>(force size)
<hr/>
<img class="cover" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508921912186-1d1a45ebb3c1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80"><br/>bobject-fit: cover #auto crop
<hr/>
<img class="contain" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508921912186-1d1a45ebb3c1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80"><br/>object-fit:contain
```